# JavaScript - regular expression to check key and value pair

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am implementing a client-side search, where the search input can accept,

```
any kind of string
(or)
name: "some string", value: 2, last_name: "some string", last_value: 2
```

I want to validate the string, to identify whether it is simple string or object string. I have a following regular expression to do it.

```
var s = 'star: asd, sta:1, sd:2';
// 'star: as, d, sta:1, sd:2';
// 'star: as, d, sta1, sd:2';
var t = s.match(/[\w]+[\:][\s]?[\w]+[\,?][\s?]/);
console.log(t);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9wryK/

This matches only the first part 'star: asd'. How to match the same possiblities with the rest of string?

Comment: Why not just add a few braces `{` and `}`, and parse your input as JSON, ensuring that your input is valid JSON?

Comment: Why do you have `?` inside your character sets brackets?

Comment: @mc10 Because it's not valid JSON. JSON requires quotes around the keys.

Comment: Yes, but I'm assuming (s)he has some control over the source input. Passing around data as a string isn't the easiest to work with.

Comment: @mc10 Its hard to expect the object notation from the users, so I am getting it in a simple way. Later, I'll convert it to a proper object notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 'global' modifier:

```
var s = 'star: asd, sta:1, sd:2';
// 'star: as, d, sta:1, sd:2';
// 'star: as, d, sta1, sd:2';
var t = s.match(/\w+:\s?\w+,?\s?/g);
console.log(t);
```

---

Also, use lookahead to capture just the pairs, without the optional comma and whitespace in between.

```
var s = 'star: asd, sta:1, sd:2';
// 'star: as, d, sta:1, sd:2';
// 'star: as, d, sta1, sd:2';
var t = s.match(/\w+:\s?\w+(?=,?\s?)/g);
console.log(t);
```